# how to show an image loading spinner with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to bind a list of images.  What's the best way to set up a spinner background while the images are loading.  I have a spinner class I can set and unset to the background image, but wondering if there is an easy way to bind to image complete events with knockout.js.

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using jquery UIs little spinner thing, I have a binding handler like

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.Loading = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

            if (valueUnwrapped == true)
                $(element).showLoading(); // Make the element visible
            else
                $(element).hideLoading();   // Make the element invisible
        }
    };
```

and then use it like

```
<div data-bind="Loading: isLoading" >
```

so, basically, you can bind it to anything on your view model that might represent its loading ( or busy ) or not.